# Cannot stop vehicles at Parking area

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using OMNeT++-5.5.1, Veins-5.0, and SUMO-1.2.0. I am trying to stop a vehicle at a parking area through setParkingAreaStop command, but I am getting the following error:

**Error: Answered with error to command 0x00: Wrong position in requestMessage after dispatching command 0. Expected command length was 70 but 2 Bytes were read.**

How can I solve this problem? please help. Thanks.